# Pandas: get first and last index of valid subsequent frames in column

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a `pandas` `DataFrame` object which contains nans. I would like to find all blocks of subsequent valid frames for each column and from these blocks the first and the last index.

Example data:

```
[
  [ 1,nan],
  [ 2,nan],
  [ 3,nan],
  [ 4,3.0],
  [ 5,1.0],
  [ 6,4.0],
  [ 7,1.0],
  [ 8,5.0],
  [ 9,9.0],
  [10,2.0],
  [11,nan],
  [12,nan],
  [13,6.0],
  [14,5.0],
  [15,3.0],
  [16,5.0]
]
```

where first column is index, second column is value I'd like to filter on. Result of this should be something like

```
[(4,10), (13,16)]
```

I would like to avoid manually iterating through the data by means of a `for`-loop for performance reasons...

#### Update 1:

Two additional criteria:

1. The valid values in the value column don't have to be equal. They can take any valid float value between -inf and +inf
2. I only need the first and the last index of valid blocks, not the NaN blocks in between.

Comment: @unutbu Thanks for editing my question accordingly. Somehow I updated it but forgot to change the numbers to reflect the actual criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
#set column names and set index by first column 
df.columns = ['idx', 'a']
df = df.set_index('idx')
#find groups
df['b'] = (df.a.isnull() != df.a.shift(1).isnull()).cumsum()
#remove NaN
df = df[df.a.notnull()].reset_index()
#aggregate first and last values of column idx  
df = df['idx'].groupby(df.b).agg(['first', 'last'])
print zip(df['first'], df['last'])
[(4, 10), (13, 16)]
```

Then I try modify solution of [cggarvey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37029271/2901002):

```
#set column names and set index by first column 
df.columns = ['idx', 'a']
df = df.set_index('idx')
#find edges 
pre =  df['a'] - df['a'].diff(-1)
pst = df['a'] - df['a'].diff(1)
a = pre.notnull() & pst.isnull()
z = pre.isnull() & pst.notnull()
print zip(a[a].index, z[z].index)
[(4, 10), (13, 16)]
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution works with the small addition that I can't compare actual values but have to rely on `df.a.isnull() != df.a.shift(1).isnull()` which returns the first and last index of each subsequent block. However it also returns the indices of the NaN-blocks in between the valid blocks. I don't need them and now somehow have to get rid of them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using Numpy. Not sure how it compares to @jezrael's solution, but you mentioned performance as a requirement so you can compare the two.

Note: This assumes your columns are named "index" and "val"

```
import numpy as np

pre = np.array(df['val'] - df.diff(-1)['val'])
pst = np.array(df['val'] - df.diff(1)['val'])

a = np.where(~np.isnan(pre) & np.isnan(pst))
z = np.where(np.isnan(pre) & ~np.isnan(pst))
output = zip(df.ix[a[0]]['index'],df.ix[z[0]]['index'])
```

Output:

```
[(4, 10), (13, 16)]
```

Comment: For some reason this does not work for me. It might be related to the fact that the valid values, as mentioned in my 1st update, can take any valid float value. Thanks nevertheless!

Comment: Ah, sorry I may have missed that. I've updated the code. 

Instead of:
a = np.where((pre == 1) & np.isnan(pst))

We do:
a = np.where(~np.isnan(pre) & np.isnan(pst))

Comment: You haven't actually *missed* it, cggarvey. I had forgotten to mention it and my example also hadn't reflected the criterion before unutbu edited it.